# No module named 'polyglot.text'; 'polyglot' is not a package

Tags: python, module, polyglot

I am new in python and I am trying to import polyglot module in my code. I have installed polyglot explained in [Polyglot Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760587/polyglot-installation), everything went good but it still gives me the same error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polyglot.text'; 'polyglot' is not a package`

When I checked polyglot in my drive, it has been installed inside directory
`D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\polyglot-16.7.4-py3.7.egg\polyglot`

which has all the needed function in my code.
I need to know where is the problem? and I need to solve it!

I need to import the following functions:

```
from polyglot.transliteration import Transliterator
from polyglot.mapping import Embedding
from polyglot.load import load_embeddings
```

Comment: Can you share code for us to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Ausrada404 I put the lines that occur the error

Answer (score 1):

Try installing:

pip install polyglot numpy morfessor pycld2 pyicu